# OneSignal doesn't increment badge number on push notification, EXCEPT from test

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I have a React Native app that is supposed to increment the push notification badge per push notification. This is on iOS

I have created the service extension, I have grouped them with an app group per the SDK, and I can definitely confirm that text messages are being received by my app.

However the badge number is just not going up!

I believe I am setting my data correctly on my server for the notifications to send:

```
    data.put("ios_badgeType", "Increase");
    data.put("ios_badgeCount", "1");
```

What else do I need to do to get my badges to increment automatically? Again, they absolutely are incrementing for the test notifications (i.e. the notifications sent directly from OneSignal to test).